# The object #f or #t is not applicable

Tags: conditional-statements, scheme, sicp

I'm trying to create a function that gets the sum of the square of the larger 2 of 3 numbers passed in. (Its exercise 1.3 in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.6))

When I run the following code I get the error ";The object #f is not applicable." If I switch the 3 and the 1 in my function call the error message will say #t instead of #f.

```
(define (sumOfSquareOfLargerTwoNumbers a b c) (
  cond (
    ( (and (> (+ a b) (+ a c) ) (> (+ a b) (+ b c) ) ) (+ (square a) (square b) ) ) 
    ( (and (> (+ a c) (+ a b) ) (> (+ a c) (+ b c) ) ) (+ (square a) (square c) ) )
    ( (and (> (+ b c) (+ a b) ) (> (+ b c) (+ a c) ) ) (+ (square b) (square c) ) )
  )
))

(sumOfSquareOfLargerTwoNumbers 1 2 3)
```

I was assuming the appropriate condition would return true and I'd get the square of the larger two numbers. Could someone please explain why I'm getting this error instead?

Comment: Brackets in Scheme are not like curly braces in other languages :) resist the temptation to open/close them in the places where you'd normally do so for curly braces, the conventions for indenting in Scheme are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are too many brackets in front of `cond` and that's causing the problem:

```
(cond (((and
```

The proper syntax for your solution should be:

```
(define (sumOfSquareOfLargerTwoNumbers a b c)
  (cond ((and (> (+ a b) (+ a c)) (> (+ a b) (+ b c)))
         (+ (square a) (square b)))
        ((and (> (+ a c) (+ a b)) (> (+ a c) (+ b c)))
         (+ (square a) (square c)))
        ((and (> (+ b c) (+ a b)) (> (+ b c) (+ a c)))
         (+ (square b) (square c)))))
```

What was happening is that the condition evaluated to a boolean, and the unexpected surrounding brackets made it look like a procedure application, so you ended up with something like this:

```
(#t 'something)
```

Which of course fails, because `#t` or `#f` are not procedures and cannot be applied. Just be careful with the brackets and use a good IDE with syntax coloring and code formatting, and you won't have this problem again.